# Why is my c:\windows\system32\wbem folder almost 100 GB and how do I reduce it?

Tags: windows, windows-8, wmi

The folder `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\` takes up almost 100 GB on my SSD drive. This doesn't feel like an optimal utilization of my SSD drive. Can it be reduced?

I've come across some references to "rebuilding your WMI repository" that seemed related to the `wbem` directory. So I've tried doing this, but the size did not decrease noticeably.

The content in the `wbem` directory is a lot of folders named `repository.xxx` where `xxx` is 001 to 096. These folders' sizes range from 758 MB to 1 140 MB. There is also a folder called merely `repository`, which is 1 078 MB in size.

I'm using Windows 8 Enterprise 64-bit (not Win 8.1). I just ran `winmgmt /verifyrepository` and got the result: `WMI repository is consistent`

Comment: How large is the `..\wbem\logs` directory?

Comment: That directory is 20 KB (one log .txt)

Comment: What version of WMF (windows management framework) do you have?  I'm stepping out to lunch, but your WMI repo is getting rebuilt constantly.  This is usually caused by incompatibilities.  Are you using the RTM version of windows 8?

Comment: I haven't installed WMF v4.0, so I have 3.0 I guess? Not RTM

Comment: Is there an error repeated in `..\wbem\logswmiprov.log`?

Comment: I didn't catch my error till now but that should be `..\wbem\logs\wmiprov.log`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I see no log entries after March this year. The modified date tells the same. Also, see my edit on running `winmgmt`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should only be one copy of
`C:\Windows\System32\wbem\Repository`.

The `Repository.xxx` folders might be WMI repository backups generated each time that
you repair the repository or recreate it.
It was once intended for the SCCM client agent to automatically try to rebuild
the WMI repository if there was a consistency issue detected,
a feature which might still exist and be the issue you are running into.

I do not know why you have so many of these folders, but it seems that WMI has an issue
on your computer. As a first-aid, you could get rid of all these folders and
rebuild the repository.

See also if the article
[Configuration Manager Client Health – Disable Automatic Remediation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanm/archive/2012/12/20/configuration-manager-client-health-disable-automatic-remediation-for-selected-machines.aspx)
relates to your setup, as it contains a registry fix for a similar problem.

It also wouldn't hurt to run the `sfc /scannow` command.

The simplest WMI rebuild is done via :

1. `net stop winmgmt`
2. Move elsewhere all folders named `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\Repository*`
3. `net start winmgmt` (should start rebuilding the repository)
4. Wait a while and then reboot
5. If everything works fine, you can junk the saved folders.

A WMI repair script that has been knocking around since ages (but I have never tried)
might itself or in some parts-of still be useful on Windows 8 :

```
Echo Fix WMI
net stop winmgmt /y
if exist %windir%\system32\wbem\repository.001 rmdir /s /q %windir%\system32\wbem\repository.001
rename %windir%\system32\wbem\repository repository.001
%windir%\system32\wbem\winmgmt /clearadap
%windir%\system32\wbem\winmgmt /kill
%windir%\system32\wbem\winmgmt /unregserver
%windir%\system32\wbem\winmgmt /reserver
%windir%\system32\wbem\winmgmt /resyncperf
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\scecli.dll
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\userenv.dll
mofcomp %windir%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.mof
mofcomp %windir%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.mfl
mofcomp %windir%\system32\wbem\rsop.mof
mofcomp %windir%\system32\wbem\rsop.mfl
cd \windows\system32\wbem
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /s %windir%\system32\wbem\*.dll') do regsvr32 /s %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /s %windir%\system32\wbem\*.mof') do mofcomp %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b %windir%\system32\wbem\*.mfl') do mofcomp %%s
net start winmgmt
%windir%\system32\wbem\wmiprvse /regserver
%windir%\system32\wbem\winmgmt /regserver
```

After all this, you might reboot and run once more `winmgmt /verifyrepository`.

Be very careful with backups and create at least a system restore point before starting,
or even better : take an image snapshot of the system disk.

Comment: Running `sfc /scannow` gave the result `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations`. I've now removed the folders and rebooted my computer, and is currently looking for any side effects

Comment: One day after clearing the stuff out, I already have a 1 GB `repository` folder and a 1 GB `repository.001` folder... I guess that I will have to live with this and re-run the procedure when the folder gets too large. Un-accepting your answer due to not knowing how to prevent this

Comment: You could maybe try the [WMI Diagnosis Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404265.aspx) and also do `"winmgmt /resetRepository`. Check the date/time on repository.xxx - if the hours are similar this might be a scheduled job. Check also the Event Viewer for interesting error messages relating to WMI.

Comment: Impressed! `winmgmt /resetRepository` did it

Comment: Is it that risky to create restore points and/or system image? I am unable to install Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 and people on stackoverflow are [suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43148261/1317018) to perform something like this to successfully install build tools

Comment: @Mahesha999: I recommend creating restore points and periodically a system image (and also before any forceful system manipulation). No harm possible, and they can be a life-saver.

Answer (score -1):

This was a known issue with the SCCM 2012 RTM release. The client was causing these issues. MS released an updated version and the issue went away. Afterwards, I was able to free up terabytes of data from the various servers.